# find Values of text box in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

i've a hyperlink report. if i click on link of parent report. it has to jump to child report.

my problem is iwant to know which values is passing to child report. Hyperlink filed is name. it is passing id values of that name. but how to get that exact value, which is passing to child report

Comment: Your question is really unclear to me.   How do you want to "get" the value?

Answer (score 0):

in text box properties of that hyperlink column, we will assign input and lable value to the child report. in case if you want know whichi value is passing to the child report. just simply use that lable value in child report.

let me know if i'm wrong.